# .NET web service secure

Tags: .net, web-services, security, authentication

Are there any good examples out there of how the following web service would work?
I would like a Windows/web client to be able to access a web service, but the client should pass a username, password, and IP address and the web service should be able to determine if it is on the list of allowed users or not before taking the request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it really "pass" the IP address? Or should that be implied by the connection?

Comment: From what i understand the ip address can be determined by the webservice once a client initiates a call. 
What i'd like is to set a list of allowed ip addresses within the webservice and have it check if it is a valid user as well as a valid ip address before going on with the request.

Comment: From comments... "I won't be able to use ssl right now"..."The information that's going to be passed is extremely confidential" - then unless you use message-based encryption instead, you have a *major* problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a WebService Login method that verifies supplied credentials. A ticket value is return if the user is validated.

This ticket is then used as a SoapHeader when using every other WebMethod.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With WCF, you can do this by using `TransportWithMessageCredential` security (over SSL) and providing your own [password validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx). At this point, however, you don't (I'm told) have access to the client IP; for that you'd need to check the IP in your method itself - you can do this using `RemoteEndpointMessageProperty`, [like so](http://web.archive.org/web/20090412074418/http://nayyeri.net/blog/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5).

If you don't want to go down the `TransportWithMessageCredential` route, then it is also valid (but ungainly) to pass the username and password as arguments to the method (as long as the transport is secure).

Comment: I won't be able to use ssl right now, so i'm trying to figure out a secure way to go about creating a webservice and allowing only certain clients access to it. The information that's going to be passed is extremely confidential and if anyone managed to get ahold of it, i'd be out of a job.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can set the web service to use NT authentication which will get a token representing the username and password.  The allowed users will be defined by the NT security.  As far as the IP address goes that will be passed in the HTTP headers by default.